SwifUI ScrollView overscrolls on paging when padding set to 0
struct TestView: View {
    @StateObject private var videoPlaybackManager = VideoPlaybackManager()
    
    // Define an array of colors
    let colors: [Color] = [.red, .green, .blue, .yellow, .orange, .purple, .pink, .gray]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            
            LazyVStack(spacing:0) {
                ForEach(colors, id: \.self) { color in
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(color)
                        .containerRelativeFrame([.horizontal, .vertical])
                }
            }
        }
        .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
        .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
        .padding(5)
    }
}

This is my SwiftUI code to test simple vertical scrolling.
Now, with this code, the scrolling works fine.

But as soon as I change padding to 0, all hell breaks loose.
struct TestView: View {
    @StateObject private var videoPlaybackManager = VideoPlaybackManager()
    
    // Define an array of colors
    let colors: [Color] = [.red, .green, .blue, .yellow, .orange, .purple, .pink, .gray]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            
            LazyVStack(spacing:0) {
                ForEach(colors, id: \.self) { color in
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(color)
                        .containerRelativeFrame([.horizontal, .vertical])
                }
            }
        }
        .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
        .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
        .padding(0)
    }
}


The scrollview starts bleeding beyond top safearea, and it overscrolls.
To me, it seems like a total bug in SwiftUI, for such a simple code. But I could be wrong. I'm relatively new to SwiftUI, although I have years of UIKit exp. which seems totally useless at this moment.
Can anyone tell me what the issue is? Do I need to implement my own paging for this?

The answer to iOS 17 SwiftUI: Color Views in ScrollView Using containerRelativeFrame Overlap When Scrolling has some possible workarounds
